# Dart & Firestore: how do you get multiple documents as streams without using whereIn, which is limited to 10 items?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, stream

For someone who understands Streams in Dart this likely is trivial. I have a List of `connections`, which are simply document id's that exist in a single collection in firestore.

I cannot use `whereIn` for my firestore query because it is limited to 10 items. So, I'm trying to loop over each connections id and then using a collection stream with a query to get one document at a time.

The code below does not work. It returns this error:

```
The method 'add' was called on null.
```

```
  Stream<List<SpecialEvents>> upcomingSpecialEventsStream(List connections) {
    if (connections.isEmpty) {
      return Stream.value(null);
    }
    
    List event;

    connections.forEach((connection) {
      event.add(_service.collectionStream(
        path: FirestorePath.specialEvents(),
        queryBuilder: (query) => query.where(
          'uid',
          isEqualTo: connection,
        ),
        builder: (data, connection) => SpecialEvents.fromMap(data, connection),
      ));
    });

    return event as Stream;
  }
```

Comment: It looks like `event` is null, probably because you never create a list.

Comment: Not sure what you mean "event.add". I was able to accomplish this using Rxdart and combining streams, however, I'm leaving this unanswered for someone that can show some code for how to add these individual firestore collection streams to a single stream. Maybe I'm barking up the wrong tree. Not having ability to do OR queries > 10 is a challenge in firestore.

Comment: The error says that you're calling `add` on `null`. The only instance of `.add`in the code you shared is `event.add(_service.collectionStream(...`, hence it seems that `event` is `null` when that line runs.